# How do I add duplicate keys to json?

Tags: python

As python dictionary doesn't allow duplicate keys, I am trying to find out a way to add multiple keys and values to json file.

I've tried to convert dict to str but that won't help as I can't append/update str.

```
numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three']

msg = {
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
      {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "content": {
          "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "version": "1.0",
          "body": [
              {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Select the number",
                  "wrap": True
              },
              {
                  "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                  "placeholder": "",
                  "choices": [
                      {
                        "title":"",
                        "value":""
                      }
                  ],
                  "separator": True,
                  "wrap": True
              }
          ],
          "actions": [
              {
                  "type": "Action.Submit",
                  "title": "Submit"
              }
          ]
          }
      }
  ],
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/"
}

for items in numbers:
    msg['attachments'][0]['content']['body'][1]['choices'][0].update({"title": items, "value": items})

print(msg['attachments'][0]['content']['body'][1]['choices'][0])
```

The output I am getting is `{'title': 'three', 'value': 'three'}` but I would like to see `{'title': 'one', 'value': 'one'},{'title': 'two', 'value': 'two'},{'title': 'three', 'value': 'three'}`

Comment: That isn't a dictionary; its a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Duplicate keys violate the purpose of JSONs/Dictioaries. What happens when you want to pull the title values? Which pair should it get? The first thing to address is what is the purpose of the title key? If it is not unique you need to find a value that is.

Comment: The way adaptive card works is you have to provide title and value pair. As this is a dropdown menu where user can select the correct option, all of them should be displayed.

Comment: @TomCider So you need a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary with the same key multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of dictionaries here, not a dictionary with duplicate keys:

```
choices = msg['attachments'][0]['content']['body'][1]['choices']

for items in numbers:
   choices.append({'title': items, 'value': items})
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!